# How to get an Instance of IWebBrowser2

Tags: c++, windows, com, ole

I am a bit new to C++, please be gentle.

I am trying to automate Internet Explorer. I have a simple Win32 console application where I am trying to create an instance of IE using a local server.

However, my call to `CoCreateInstance()` doesn't return an object to initialize my `IWebBrowser2` variable.

I could use some help to see what I am missing.

Here is my code:

```
HRESULT InstanciateIEResult;
HRESULT NavigateResult;
HRESULT ShowBrowserResult;

VARIANT * empty = new VARIANT();

BSTR URL = L"bing.com";
IWebBrowser2*    pBrowser2;

InstanciateIEResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&pBrowser2);


if(pBrowser2)
{
    //never reach here
    NavigateResult = pBrowser2->Navigate(URL, empty, empty, empty, empty);
    ShowBrowserResult = pBrowser2->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
}
```

I am also not sure how to decode what the `HRESULT` returns. If you know, that would be helpful as well.

I was looking at documentation on [IWebBrowser2 interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CoCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Maybe you didn't call `CoInitialize(NULL)`. Show all relevant code, not bits and pieces.

Comment: Thank you, that made it work. I didn't make that call and it didn't work. If you can turn that into an answer I will give you credit.

Comment: Had you looked at the return value of `CoCreateInstance()`, you would have seen that it was returning `0x800401F0`, aka `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` ("CoInitialize has not been called").  Don't ignore return values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `CoInitialize()` before using COM objects.

Also, you need to use `SysAllocString()` to allocate the string.

Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <MsHTML.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <ExDispid.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT InstanciateIEResult;
    HRESULT NavigateResult;
    HRESULT ShowBrowserResult;

    VARIANT empty;
    VariantInit(&empty);

    IWebBrowser2* browser = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL,
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&browser);

    if (browser)
    {
        BSTR URL = SysAllocString(L"bing.com");
        NavigateResult = browser->Navigate(URL, &empty, &empty, &empty, &empty);
        SysFreeString(URL);

        ShowBrowserResult = browser->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
        browser->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me convert a BSTR to  VARIANT or initialize a Variant with a string of characters?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: please post a new question for that.  It doesn't apply to this question.